# Resizing textarea with transition is laggy

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

When I've set transition for `textarea` and I want to resize it by the resize handle on the bottom right, the resize is laggy.

You can see that in this simple example:

```css
textarea{
  outline : none;
  border: 3px solid black;
  resize: vertical;
   -webkit-transition:all ease-in-out 0.7s;
   -moz-transition:all ease-in-out 0.7s;
   -ms-transition:all ease-in-out 0.7s;
   -o-transition:all ease-in-out 0.7s;
   transition:all ease-in-out 0.7s;
}

textarea:focus{
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Resize me by my resize handle please</textarea>
```

Without transition the resize is smooth but I want to have transition for border color changing.

I thought about not using transition on the `textarea` and use animation instead like this:

```css
textarea{
  outline : none;
  border: 3px solid black;
  resize: vertical;
}

textarea:focus{
  animation: animate 0.7s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animate { 
  100% {
    border-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea>Resize me by my resize handle please</textarea>
```

As you can see I solved the problem with animation partially, but on the focus out I don't have transition.

Please offer a solution in pure CSS. If I can solve the lag without using animation, or solve it with animation focus out which I don't know how to select focus out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are applying the transition to **all** the properties and when resizing you are changing the height/width of your element so they are affected by the transition; thus you have this laggy effect.

To avoid this simply apply transition to the needed property, in this case the `border-color`.

```css
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
  resize: vertical;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.7s;
}

textarea:focus {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Resize me by my resize handle please</textarea>
```

---

Concerning the animation issue : When the focus is removed the animation also is removed so you get back to the initial state immediately. To fix this you may consider two animations.

**This is simply a fix for the second method and not the solution I recommend as the above one is the suitable one.**

```css
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
  resize: vertical;
  animation: focus-out 0.7s linear forwards;
}

textarea:focus {
  animation: focus-in 0.7s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes focus-out {
  from {
    border-color: red;
  }
  to {
    border-color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes focus-in {
  to {
    border-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea>Resize me by my resize handle please</textarea>
```